# Equilibrium Temperature in a Rod

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider heat flow in a rod of length $l$
\begin{align*}
    u_t = ku_{xx} - hu, 0 < x < l\\
    u(0,t) = u(l,t) = 0, t > 0\\
    u(x,0) = f(x), 0 \leq x \leq l\\
\end{align*}
I am trying to find the equilibrium temperature. 
I am new to these problems but I think the equilibrium temperature is reached when $u_t = 0$. Thus I say that,
\begin{align*}
    0 &= ku_xx - hu \\
\end{align*}
For fixed $t=0$ define $y(x) := u(x,0)$ so we have an ODE in $y$
\begin{align*}
    0 &= ky''(x) - hy(x)\\
    y(x) &= \frac{c_1 k e^{hx/k}}{h} + c_2
\end{align*}
From the boundary condition we know that $y(x) = f(x)$, but this is not enough to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$. It seems like we need more information. I know that we also have that $u(0,t) = y(0) = 0$ but even if we also had that we could still not solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$. I am confused how to proceed can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the equilibrium temperature is found when $u_t=0$. However, you should think of this as the temperature as $t \to \infty$, not when $t=0$. That is, $f(x)$ should have no bearing on the equilibrium solution.  So, we have to solve

$$ku_{xx} = hu$$
with boundary conditions
$$u(0)=u(\ell) = 0.$$

Then, the solutions are of the form

$$u(x) = C_1 e^{x\sqrt{h/k}} + C_2 e^{-x\sqrt{h/k}}.$$

Using the boundary conditions, I calculated $C_1 = e^{-\ell \sqrt{h/k}}-e^{\ell \sqrt{h/k}}$ and $C_2 = -C_1$.